# Reverse excel cell contents using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a column (C) in Excel with around 400 rows (variable) with alphanumeric values. What I want is to reverse each cells content to be reversed i.e something like

Xy1234 ----> 4321yX

So far I have,

```
Sub Rev()
    Dim C As Excel.Range

    For Each C In sheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Cells
        C(1, 8).FormulaR1C1 = "=RevStr(RC[-5])*1"
    Next C



End Sub

Public Function RevStr(ByVal Rng As Excel.Range)
    RevStr = StrReverse(Rng.Value)
End Function
```

But instead of the desired output all I get in column H is `#NAME?` in all the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a module, add this function to it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function ReverseContent(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
    ReverseContent = StrReverse(myRange.Value)
End Function
```

And then call it in your sheet using:

```
=ReverseContent(A1)
```

This wouldn't replace the contents of your cells of course, but you could easily copy and paste them over? In this way it performs like any other excel function.

Answer (score 0):

I think calling RevStr from .net and then write the result to the cell instead on calling it from Excel would work